# title not showing when dragging and dropping using react-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am using `react-dnd` for drag and drop in my project. However, there seems to be an issue with title attribute. Tooltip is not showing on dragging and droping an element.`Tooltip` starts showing if there is something clicked on the project.

https://codesandbox.io/s/0mqjymk5zl

Drag and drop an element, then hover on any of the element, tooltip won't show. If you click at any place, then tooltip will start showing.

Comment: I've looked over your codesandbox and it works fine on chrome v65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: I don't seem to get that issue. If I drag and drop something, then hover over any of the elements right after the tooltip still shows. I don't have to click somewhere to get the tooltip to show. What browser are you using?

Comment: @DanielAndrei  I am also using  chrome Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit). Did you dragged and dropped and then tried hover?

Comment: Yes, and it works alright.

Comment: ok. Its not working for me. I'll try to share a video of it.